# How to make parameterized query involving multiple tables with ADO.NET / C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-injection, parameterized

I would like to make parameterized query for SQLquery that can be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table2 WHERE Col3 IN (1, 2, 3));
```

The values come from WS interface and although I can trust the consumers I want to play it safe and use parameterized query involving DbParameters to prevent SQL injection. How to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use stored procedures?

Comment: @Ankit: no I can't. I have to make existing code to handle conditions that depend on another table and it would be too big change to use stored procedures.

Comment: Do you have some code that goes with this?

Comment: which bits here are variable? is it just the `IN` values?

Comment: @Ankit eugh; I will personally shoot anyone who does that near any code-base of mine; that is a terrible and very wrong solution to the problem. (edit: this was a response to a now-deleted comment about quote-doubling, etc)

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. It's actually Col3 that comes from outside. Col1 and Col2 does not come from outside. But when i do this for single table every column is parametrized.

Comment: @MikeC. I add a little code to the question.

Comment: @matti what do you mean by a column being parameterized. Columns are **never** parameterized. That isn't even possible.

Comment: @Marc : I meant every value for every column in WHERE-clause. I was thinking that I make 1st parameter for value for Col1 (SELECT...). Now it looks like I parametrize only values for Col3. But maybe there's nothing wrong with that. I was probably thinking this from different view than rest :)

Comment: @matti well, in the example you *show*, the **only** thing suitable to be parameterized is the values `1, 2, 3`. If you want to change the query in any other way, it would be good to show an example, because it could impact the most appropriate approach.

Comment: @Marc I was thinking is it possible to parameterize SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Col1 IN (@Params), which in turn would have parameters for Status-es somehow. Maybe that was just stupid.

Comment: @matti no, the thought isn't stupid - but ADO.NET makes it tricky; hence why we went out of our way to make this *simple* to do when we wrote "dapper". See my answer for an example of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point, as you note, is to use parameters. `IN` clauses are notoriously problematic for that, annoyingly. Now, if you know the values are all integers (for example you are taking an `int[]` parameter to your C# method), then you can *just about get away with* things like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table2 WHERE Col3 IN ("
+ string.Join(",", values) + "))"; // please don't!!!
```

It is horrible, suggests a very bad practice (if somebody copies it for strings, you are in a world of pain), and can't use query plan caching. You *could* do something like:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table2 WHERE Col3 IN (");
int idx = 0;
foreach(var val in values) {
    if(idx != 0) sb.Append(',');
    sb.Append("@p").Append(idx);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" + idx, val);
    idx++
}
sb.Append("))");
cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
```

Which is preferable but awkward.

Or simplest: with a tool like [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper), let *the library* worry about it:

```
var data = conn.Query<YourType>(
    "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table2 WHERE Col3 IN @values)",
    new { values });
```

Here *dapper* spots the usage and "does the right thing". It also handles the "0 values" case for you.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I'm familiar how to make parameterized queries. As I told you I was just thinking different (wrong) way. So the bottom line is to parameterize the "2nd query" just like for single table. So this did not differ in any way what I've been doing many times.

Comment: @matti absolutely not different at all; ADO.NET doesn't *care* what the command-text is. The only interesting technical point in the specific query you show is the `IN` clause - which is a real PITA to parameterize properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT Col2 FROM Table2 WHERE Col3 = @myparam", conn);

//define parameters used in command object
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@myparam";
param.Value         = "myvalue";

//add new parameter to command object
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

// get data stream
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Check out this link for more details:
http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that I have to create a DbParameter for every value like: SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Col1 IN (@Params) which in turn would have parameters for Status-es.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is parameterizing each individual IN clause so that you can pass through a variable number of IDs.

Have a look at this useful article as to one approach to solve this: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/116/Parameterized-IN-clauses-with-ADO.NET-and-LINQ

Basically, it involves a little bit of string manipulation to build up the parameterized list of IN clauses, so you end up with a SQL statement that looks like this for your particular example with 3 IDs:

```
select * from TABLE1 where COL1 in (select COL2 from TABLE2 where COL3 IN (@p1, @p2, @p3));
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made code to handle the IN automatically. However I was thinking is it possible to parameterize SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Col1 IN (@Params), which in turn would have parameters for Status-es somehow. Maybe that was just stupid.